# Azure Subscription messed up in VS2015 and New Portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azureportal

For some reason, my Azure Subscription has suddenly become inaccessible on the new portal.azure.com site and in the Server Explorer in VS 2015.

This just happened out of the blue yesterday. Has something changed in the portal recently with regard to resource groups or anything. Has there been some sort of Active Directory change ?

In the old portal I can see my app services, but these are no longer visible in the new portal or in visual studio server explorer. How weird!

Is this possibly a billing issue ? 
I have not received any emails to say my bill was not paid ?

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to perms, but hard to say...  I would open a support request in the portal and if you can't even do that for some reason, tweet @AzureSupport

Comment: yeah, I opened the request, but by the time they got back, it had resolved itself!

Comment: Wow - AzureSupport is much better than anticipated!  ;) glad it's working now...